# ELK - Shield auth problems

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-shield

I'm trying to setup Shield for Elasticsearch, but had some trouble

When I try to start Elasticsearch like:

```
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
```

all work as expected, but when I'm trying to start/restart Elasticsearch like:

```
 /etc/init.d/elasticsearch srart
```

I've got error described below

```
[2015-02-17 21:44:09,662][ERROR][shield.audit.logfile     ] [Tusk] [rest] [authentication_failed]   origin_address=[/192.168.88.17:58291], principal=[es_admin], uri=[/_aliases?pretty=true]
```

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Elasticsearch: 1.4.3
Shield: 1.0.1
Elasticsearch and Shield were running with default settings

Answer (score 5):

If your elasticsearch configs are not in **`/usr/share/elasticsearch`** but lets say at **`/etc/elasticsearch`**
Then just move the **`usr/share/elasticsearch/config/shield`** to **`/etc/elasticseach`**
Take care that if you start elasticsearch with the user elasticsearch that the new **`/etc/elasticsearch/shield`** folder belongs to the user elasticsearch.

If that doesn't make it, then also see this 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/shield/current/getting-started.html#_configuring_your_environment

Comment: jup. on a Centos7 the following did the trick:  `sudo ln -s /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/shield /etc/elasticsearch`

Comment: Worked for me. Too bad this isn't documented anywhere in the official docs.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened with me when i tried to add shield to our elasticsearch cluster to add auth based access to elasticsearch data.

I was on ubuntu 14.04 machine and elasticsearch was installed using a .deb package from [elastic-download-link](https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.4.4.deb).

Elasticsearch was using a service startup script from

> /etc/init.d/elasticsearch

in which the configuration was mentioned as:

```
# Elasticsearch configuration directory
CONF_DIR=/etc/$NAME
```

But when i tried to install shield plugin on elasticsearch from [this-link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/installing-shield.html)
and tried to add user on shield by following [es-docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/_managing_users_in_an_esusers_realm.html) using this command.

```
sudo bin/shield/esusers useradd es_admin -r admin
```

shield configuration was being updated in

> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/shield/

but elasticsearch server was expecting configuration files to be in

> /etc/elasticsearch/shield/

due to this mismatch in read configuration file for shield and new updated file with newly added users on shield causing this authentication failure.

This can be solved either by moving

> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/shield/
>   to
>   /etc/elasticsearch/shield/

or by changing conf file location in

> /etc/init.d/elasticsearch

as

```
# Elasticsearch configuration directory
CONF_DIR=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/
```